# Width of multiline UILabel in UITableView keeps shrinking with autolayout

Tags: ios, uitableview, uilabel, autolayout

I have a UILabel functioning as a title in my UITableViewCell.  It displays fine the first time it is used, but each time it is redisplayed the width shrinks.  All my layout is done in IB, nothing in code at the moment.

[EDIT]
The left hand side of the label is pinned to the (barely visible) box that says "New Words".  The right hand side is pinned to the superview.  Height is set to 44px.

I am able to fix this by using the following code in layoutSubviews.  I don't like it at all though since it involves setting the frame.  I would like to understand the underlying problem.

```
[super layoutSubviews];
CGRect frame = self.titleLabel.frame;
CGSize size = self.titleLabel.intrinsicContentSize;
frame.size.width = size.width;
frame.size.height = 44;
self.titleLabel.frame = frame;
[super layoutSubviews];
```

Here are a few screenshots of the problem:

First time:

[image: Start]

Second time:

[image: Middle]

Third+ time:

[image: End]

Comment: Are you using a custom subclass for your cell? If so, do you have any code in the .m file? What constraints did you have on the label when you made these screen shots?

Comment: Please see my edits above.

Comment: Well, if you're using auto layout, you shouldn't be setting frames, but I don't know why having a left and right constraint doesn't keep your label the same width. Are those constraints "=" rather than ">=" or "<=". Are their priorities 1000? Are you doing something in heightForRowAtIndexPath to vary the height of the cells? If so, you should post that code too.

Comment: Right, setting the frame should not be necessary.  The constraints are just basic "Leading Space to view = 20" "Trailing Space to superview = 20".  Priority 1000.  I'm not changing the height of the view anywhere.